# Trying to get data from a table using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Trying to get the "all splits" line of numbers from https://insider.espn.com/nba/player/splits/_/id/532/type/nba/year/2003/category/perGame (html code is in the picture) my code returns the 'all splits' text instead of the numbers I'm looking for. How do I go about changing the lookups in the GetStats function area to get the numbers instead of the first column descriptors.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd
import csv

urls = []
data = []

for year in range(2003, 2005):
    for page in range(1, 9):
        url = f'http://www.espn.com/nba/hollinger/statistics/_/page/{page}/year/{year}/qualified/false'
        if url is not None:
            urls.append(url)

    def GetData(url):
        names_list = []  # names of players
        pers = []  # player efficency ratings
        playeridlist = []  # list of player ids to be used in making new stats searchable url
        statsurls = []  # list of urls generated to get player stats

# makes a pattern for the function to look for
        pattern = re.compile('playerId=(\d+)')

# setsup soup function
        req = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

# finds players names and adds to list
        names = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and 'playerId' in tag['href'])
        bodytext = names.text
        names_list.append(bodytext)

# finds plays player efficency rating and adds to list
        pertag = soup.find('td', class_='sortcell')
        per = pertag.text
        pers.append(per)

# finds player id
        names = soup.find('a', href=pattern)
        player_id = names['href'].split('playerId=')[1]
        playeridlist.append(player_id)

# uses player id to make a list of new urls for that player and get stats
        for player_id in playeridlist:
            statsurl = f"https://insider.espn.com/nba/player/splits/_/id/{player_id}/type/nba/year/{year}/category/perGame"
            if statsurl is not None:
                statsurls.append(statsurl)

# parses stats to get stats
        def GetStats(statsurl):  # GO BACK AND MAKE A THREAD EXECUTER STATEMENT WITHIN GETDATA FUNCTION BELOW THIS!!!
            statsreq = requests.get(statsurl)
            statssoup = BeautifulSoup(statsreq.text, 'lxml')
            focusing_search = statssoup.find('tr', class_='Table__TR Table__TR--sm Table__even', attrs={'data-idx': '1'})
            playerstathtml = focusing_search.find('td', class_='Table__TD')
            stat_values = [playerstats.text for playerstats in playerstathtml]
            print(stat_values)
            
   GetStats("https://insider.espn.com/nba/player/splits/_/id/532/type/nba/year/2003/category/perGame")


        #name_and_stats_list = dict(map(lambda i, j: (i, j), names_list, pers))


        print(f"{bodytext}: {per}")
        print(player_id)

GetData('http://www.espn.com/nba/hollinger/statistics/_/page/1/year/2003/qualified/false')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `all_splits` stats from:
https://insider.espn.com/nba/player/splits/_/id/532/type/nba/year/2003/category/perGame

This is what I did:

- I grabbed the table body using `soup.select`
- Then I grabbed the headings and relevant stats by iterating through the columns/rows.

The list comprehension provides the text in list format, which is easy to convert to a dataframe.

#### Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://insider.espn.com/nba/player/splits/_/id/532/type/nba/year/2003/category/perGame'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

t = soup.select('main#fittPageContainer div.Table__Scroller > table > tbody')
headings = [h.text for h in t[0].find_next('tr').find_all('td')]
all_splits = [h.text for h in t[0].find_all('tr')[1].find_all('td')]

df = pd.DataFrame([all_splits], columns=headings)
print(df)
```

#### Output:

[image: all_splits]